# Android - launch configuration activity on widget click - does not work

Tags: java, android, onclick, widget

First, I read all similar questions and responses on xda and also google documentation. However, still I don't know why my code does not work.

Widget code:

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider
{

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetConfigureActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.my_widget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_container, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        // When the user deletes the widget, delete the preference associated with it.
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            MyWidgetConfigureActivity.deleteTitlePref(context, appWidgetIds[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context)
    {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context)
    {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId)
    {

        CharSequence widgetText = MyWidgetConfigureActivity.loadTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);
        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

My widget layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"
                android:background="#09C"
                android:id="@+id/widget_container">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appwidget_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/appwidget_text"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/appwidget_text"
        android:background="#09C"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Problem - my config activity is launched only on adding widget to home screen. After I tap already added widget, nothing happens. Can you tell me what's the problem?

[edit]
My activity code:

```
package com.example.michal.widgettest2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


/**
 * The configuration screen for the {@link MyWidget MyWidget} AppWidget.
 */
public class MyWidgetConfigureActivity extends Activity
{

    int mAppWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;
    EditText mAppWidgetText;
    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.example.michal.widgettest2.MyWidget";
    private static final String PREF_PREFIX_KEY = "appwidget_";

    public MyWidgetConfigureActivity()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        // Set the result to CANCELED.  This will cause the widget host to cancel
        // out of the widget placement if the user presses the back button.
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_widget_configure);
        mAppWidgetText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.appwidget_text);
        findViewById(R.id.add_button).setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);

        // Find the widget id from the intent.
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
        {
            mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }

        // If this activity was started with an intent without an app widget ID, finish with an error.
        if (mAppWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID)
        {
            finish();
            return;
        }

        mAppWidgetText.setText(loadTitlePref(MyWidgetConfigureActivity.this, mAppWidgetId));
    }

    View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            final Context context = MyWidgetConfigureActivity.this;

            // When the button is clicked, store the string locally
            String widgetText = mAppWidgetText.getText().toString();
            saveTitlePref(context, mAppWidgetId, widgetText);

            // It is the responsibility of the configuration activity to update the app widget
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            MyWidget.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId);

            // Make sure we pass back the original appWidgetId
            Intent resultValue = new Intent();
            resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
            finish();
        }
    };

    // Write the prefix to the SharedPreferences object for this widget
    static void saveTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId, String text)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
        prefs.putString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, text);
        prefs.commit();
    }

    // Read the prefix from the SharedPreferences object for this widget.
    // If there is no preference saved, get the default from a resource
    static String loadTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String titleValue = prefs.getString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, null);
        if (titleValue != null)
        {
            return titleValue;
        } else
        {
            return context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
        }
    }

    static void deleteTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
        prefs.remove(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId);
        prefs.commit();
    }
}
```

My activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/configure"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/appwidget_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_widget"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where do you use `static void updateAppWidget`?

Comment: It's used on button click in my configuration activity, so widget should be updated from my config activity (this code was auto generated by Android Studio). But - why my configuration activity is not showing on click?

Answer (score 5):

You need to update your `static void updateAppWidget` to support click action for editing the widget.

```
static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int appWidgetId){

  CharSequence widgetText = MyWidgetConfigureActivity.loadTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);
  // Construct the RemoteViews object
  RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget);
  views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////required
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetConfigureActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);    //set widget id
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

  RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.my_widget);
  views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_container, pendingIntent);
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
  appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still there are some problems. Now my activity is showing on click, but it closes immediately. I updated my question and added activity code/layout. What's wrong?

Comment: I figuret it out - on click, activity is called with invalid widget id. But I'm not sure where can I set correct id?

Comment: Should I add putExtra with widget id? Where to add it?

Comment: I didn't help. I need to to put widget id in onUpdate override, not in updateAppWidget as you suggested. However, I'm not sure why.

Comment: And it still does not work as should... if there are many widget instances, update goes to incorrect one (not the one who invoked config dialog).

Comment: Why do you have to add the click listener on every update? Surely it only has to be done once when the widget is started up?

Comment: @RichardBarraclough every time you update widget, it kills reference to the old remote views and create new ones. Hence you need to set everything all together. RemoteView work quite different than the regular view objects as we deal in activities/fragments.